# Ruby Rake FILE method doesn't work

Tags: ruby, methods, rake, rakefile

It's first time I'm using rake, and I figure a problem with file dependencies.

To make a test, in `Rakefile.rb` I put this code:

```
task :ffile do

    f1 = "config.yaml"
    f2 = "Rakefile.rb"

    if File.file? f1 then puts "## test file task on #{f1}" end
    if File.file? f2 then puts "## test file task on #{f2}" end

    file "#{f1}" => "#{f2}" do 
        puts "lol"
    end

    file "#{f2}" => "#{f1}" do 
        puts "lul"
    end

    file "#{f1}" do 
        puts "lil"
    end

    file "#{f2}" do 
        puts "lal"
    end

end
```

I'm on Windows 10, and when run

```
rake ffile
```

the result is

```
Starting rake operations...
## test file task on config.yaml
## test file task on Rakefile.rb
```

that is **file method** do nothing in all four cases. I tried also to remove the quote (i.e. `f1` instead `"#{f1}"` and so on in all `file`) but obtain the same result.
Clearly every time I save `Rakefile.rb` while testing, so I'm sure that should be trigger one of the file methos.

There's syntax error? It's troubleshoot with Windows 10?

Thanks

Comment: What is `file` supposed to do? Can you post the code ?

Answer (score 1):

The `file` method is actually a DSL to define a file task https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/b63f7d33d72782f646ef95da10300d273c9b8006/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb#L75, which has to be invoked manually.

```
Rake::Task[f1].invoke
Rake::Task[f2].invoke
```

Since your dsl definitions have circular dependency: `TOP => config.yaml => Rakefile.rb => config.yaml`, adding the above code will raise an error.

But I think you could get the idea how to invoke the file tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks larrylv, I've understood!

I have two errors:

1. circular, as larrylv said
2. and I don't invoke the file task! (larrylv said)

So I report a simple example that works

```
f1 = "config.yaml"
f2 = "Rakefile.rb"

task :ffile => ["#{f1}"]

file "#{f1}" => ["#{f2}"] do 
     puts "lul"
end
```

With this, the command `rake ffile` works as aspected.

Thanks!